# Virtuemart 2 pdf generation

Tags: php, pdf, joomla, virtuemart

Where in the file structure will i find the php file which generates the pdf invoices for virtuemart 2?

Im trying to customise it for an insurance brokers website to instead send out the insurance documents as a pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the PDF generation section under.

```
in the front end compnents/com_virtuemart/view/invoice/
```

they are using the PDF section here iam using VM2.0.6 in its that section not working.
so for my requirement is almost same to you i did it with DomPdf creation option.
Create the PDF content first as HTML then easily convert to PDF.

You can find the Dompdf here

```
http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/source/browse/tags/dompdf_0-6-0_beta3/
```

create you own path for your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I actually already found it and have been able to customise it for my needs. Which part of it was not working for you?

Comment: @SeanLang mine is different case bocoz the content of pdf is ritch with css and image it was not good with VM PDF so iam used DOMPDF it will support standard css and images. Thanks for your interest